# How to create a diurnal plot that includes standard deviation bars (Reproducible example)

Tags: r, dataframe, plot, time, graph

I have a set of data over a two month period at hourly time intervals (df provided as example subset).

I want to be able to create a diurnal plot over 24 hours and also include "error" bars that is the standard deviation for each corresponding hour within the 24 hour period (something like the snip provided below)

If anyone has any idea on how to do this I would be very grateful.

Reproducible example:

```
df <- structure(list(date = structure(c(1623394800, 1623398400, 1623402000, 
1623405600, 1623409200, 1623412800, 1623416400, 1623420000, 1623423600, 
1623427200, 1623430800, 1623434400, 1623438000, 1623441600, 1623445200, 
1623448800, 1623452400, 1623542400, 1623546000, 1623549600, 1623553200, 
1623556800, 1623560400, 1623564000, 1623481200, 1623484800, 1623488400, 
1623492000, 1623495600, 1623499200, 1623502800, 1623506400, 1623510000, 
1623513600, 1623517200, 1623520800, 1623524400, 1623528000, 1623531600, 
1623535200, 1623538800), tzone = "", class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
)), Normalized = c(0.0791523227961842, 0.0387684846348657, 0.0169612120277537, 
0, 0.00861521880774794, 0.0498067337322928, 0.237995419564037, 
0.43372242185256, 0.571296697188785, 0.57452740424169, 0.586642555690086, 
0.660410366731428, 0.78883097208442, 0.713717033104368, 0.718293868095984, 
0.764331443599887, 0.716140063394047, 1, 0.886130921162445, 0.709001242970692, 
0.648271067590662, 0.554223643217422, 0.402398204767348, 0.272924844755757, 
0.243403231723798, 0.132908051518466, 0.0257867699453584, 0.00723032746812717, 
0.010604226100351, 0.0662735535320448, 0.140921060769998, 0.253946664949497, 
0.29105954990396, 0.38299828763206, 0.568984449733401, 0.679901367267761, 
0.691288275151516, 0.670623146029145, 0.686649164532208, 0.672310095345257, 
0.814435575227687)), row.names = c(NA, -41L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using ggplot2 and dplyr:

```
library(ggplot2); library(dplyr)
```

First you have to define your errobars, I've just used the standard deviation of each hour as representative error bar length. If you want to use a different group for the standard deviation you can just change the entry in `group_by`:

```
df <- df %>% mutate( day = format(date, "%d"),
               hour = format(date, "%H")) %>% 
  group_by(day) %>% 
  summarize(errorbar = sd(Normalized),
            date=date, day=day) %>% 
  left_join(df, ., by="date")
```

Then I've used the function `geom_errorbar` to create the errorbar:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=date, y=Normalized)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point() +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=Normalized-errorbar, ymax=Normalized+errorbar), width=.2,
                position=position_dodge(.05)) +
  theme_bw()
```

Which gives the following solution:
[image]

If you want to use different plots e.g. per day you can just add `+facet_wrap(.~day)` to the plot to achieve this.